# Android : best practice several xml or just one

Tags: android, xml

i've a question (of course :D) What is the best solution, between (for example a menu) : Create several menu in XML, because in my app i will have a menu with one option, an other with 3, etc... OR to create just ONE MENU XML, and to use setVisibility and other to show just item i want in every parts of my app ?

What's the best practice according you ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use different *.xml files for different menus. If not, it will be really hard to manage all the widgets with the visibility method, not to mention waste of running time

Comment: i think to, but it more easy for us, but for android, there is a difference ? (for the execution of the code, etc... i said for "menu", but it just an example of course)